# ValueError when I'm trying to implement lost password

Tags: python, django

I was playing around with Python, I'm new in Python Language so I'm trying to reset a lost password but I come across ValueError Exception here's my code:

models.py:

```
def forgot(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
            lostpassword = LostPassword.objects.create(user=user, key=new_key())
            message = 'http://%s:%s/lostpassword/change/%s/' % (
                request.META['SEVER_NAME'],
                request.META['SEVER_PORT'],
                lostpassword.key)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            message = 'Unknown user'
    else:
        message = ''
    return render_to_response('homepage/forgot.html', {'message': message})
```

forms.py:

```
  class ForgotForm(forms.Form):
      help_string="Your password will be emailed to you"
      user = forms.CharField()
```

views.py:

```
  def forgot(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          try:
              user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
              lostpassword = LostPassword.objects.create(user=user, key=new_key())
              message = 'http://%s:%s/lostpassword/change/%s/' % (
                  request.META['SEVER_NAME'],
                  request.META['SEVER_PORT'],
                  lostpassword.key)
          except User.DoesNotExist:
              message = 'Unknown user'
      else:
          message = ''
      return render_to_response('homepage/forgot.html', {'message': message})

url.py:

     urlpatterns = patterns('blog.apps.homepage.views',
 url(r'^$', 'index', name='homepage_index'),
 url(r'^about/$', 'about', name='homepage_about'),
 url(r'^contact/$', 'contact', name='homepage_contact'),
 url(r'^archive/$', 'archive', name='homepage_archive'),
 url(r'^login/$', 'login', name='homepage_login'),
 url(r'^register/$', 'register', name='homepage_register'),
 url(r'^gallery/$', 'gallery', name='homepage_gallery'),
 url(r'^profile/$', 'profile', name='homepage_profile'),
 url(r'^welcome/$', 'welcome', name='homepage_welcome'),
 url(r'^validation/$', 'validation', name='homepage_welcome'),
 url(r'^success/$', 'success', name='homepage_success'),
 url(r'^add_organisation/$', 'add_organisation', name='homepage_add_organisation'),
 url(r'^hallo/$', 'hallo', name='homepage_hallo'),
 url(r'^editMe/$', 'editMe', name='homepage_editMe'),
     url(r'^forgot/$', 'forgot', 'blog.apps.homepage.views.forgot'),

)
```

forgot.html (template):

```
<form method="post" action=".">
    Username: <input type"text" name="username" /> <br />
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
<p>
    {{ message }}
</p>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
101. request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
252. sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
252. sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
156. kwargs.update(self.default_args)

Exception Type: ValueError at /forgot/ 
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

What is it that I don't do alright?

Comment: You posted your view twice instead of your models - but more to the point, you didn't post your urls, which is where I think the error is.

Comment: No, post the *whole* urls.py please.

Comment: I'm sorry I posted all now. Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to the `url` function is supposed to be a dictionary consisting of extra arguments to pass to the view function. For some reason, you've got `'blog.apps.homepage.views.forgot'` there instead - but you've already set the view function, `forgot`.

By the way, note that Django already includes a "reset password" feature - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset).